# When and why did most educated people start saying "all of the <noun>"?

Tags: prepositions

It is correct to say :

> "All of them are lovely."
>   "I'd like all of those."

"All of" before a pronoun is correct.

It is not correct to say:

> "All of the airlines are on strike."
>   "All of my friends are going to a party".

In those sentences you leave the "of" out if you want to be correct.

Why is everyone doing that now?

Comment: Do you have some sort of reference to back up your assertions?

Comment: Judgments like “it is not correct”, followed by something that is so exceedingly commonplace and ubiquitous that it can in fact only really be described as perfectly correct (at least in spoken language) generally do not sit well with most people here. As for why, I would have thought that’s rather obvious. You give the answer yourself: with pronouns, ‘of’ is required—that is simply extended to regular nouns, too.

Comment: @Janus: My impression from a couple of minutes with NGrams is that the phenomenon is more marked in AmE than BrE. My other impression, (from brief reflection) is that the emerging form is actually a move towards *standardisation*. Since we're *not* likely to abandon the preposition in forms like *"All **of** us are Anglophones"*, the next best thing is to start slipping the preposition in wherever else we can. I realise all **of** my fellow countrymen aren't exactly "behind the mule" on this one yet - but I say *"Bring it on!"*

Comment: @Fumble, yup. It’s a simple case of analogy. And analogy nearly always wins and makes things more regular.

Comment: @virmaior: We can quibble about what exactly OP means by "correct", but there's plenty of evidence to back up the fact that (pronoun contexts excepted) ***of*** is still relatively uncommon (and by implication is probably considered at the very least "informal" by many speakers, even if they do actually use it themselves).

Comment: You say "some of the" and not "some the"; "none of the" and not "none the"; "any of the" and not "any the". The rule for "all" is simply being normalized to match the rest of these quantifiers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: in fact, [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all+of+them%2C+all+them&year_start=1650&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Call%20of%20them%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Call%20them%3B%2Cc0) shows people used to say "all them" rather than "all of them" much more often than they do now.

Comment: If 'everyone [is] doing [it] now', and you say it's incorrect, I'm not sure we can help you here.

Comment: "Of the airlines, all are on strike." "Of my friends, all are going to the party." Seems pretty straight-forward to me.

Comment: When I was in grade school every teacher I had disallowed us from saying "all of the".  Even if it were not technically incorrect then it would still be breaking the rule that the best choice of words is the fewest prepositions.  Would you say "get off my car" or "get off of my car" to someone leaning on your car?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all%20the,all%20of%20the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,all%20the;,c0;.t1;,all%20of%20the;,c0) shows that "all the" always been much more common than "all of the", but has been steadily declining since 1800. "All of the" was rare before about 1900, when it had a noticeable rise, and has continued to increase very slowly, though it remains will below "all the".

Comment: All [of] this is perfectly true, but I'm not upvoting because I don't see how it actually answers the question. The slow rise of *"all **of**"* is somewhat more marked with [all {of} my time](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all+my+time%2Call+of+my+time&year_start=1870&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Call%20my%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Call%20of%20my%20time%3B%2Cc0), and you can see from that NGram it's much more AmE than BrE.

Comment: -1 Not a personal opinion, an empirical fact: Avoid drawing inferences (formulating answers) solely from nGrams.